# Siri doesn't work in macOS Mojave

Tags: mojave, siri

I have a MacBook Pro 15 with TB. The problem is that Siri doesn't hear me when a click the icon in the touch bar. I check my microphone settings and it looks good. I have macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

[image]

But when I click on the icon as I say, nothing happens. It doesn't show the small color waves that are observed when Siri is listening to you. I try to restart the computer but doesn't work. [Here](https://youtu.be/XaRYZR-rbus) is a little clip of what happened.

[image]

Comment: Do you see mic level if you speak whilst the Sound control panel is open?

Comment: @Tetsujin yes microphone works normal. I can even record and audio.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything, but I ended erasing my hard drive. I think is a bug of the version of macOS. So I suggest if Siri is not an important feature for you, just ignore this bug. On the other hand, the solution I find so far is back up your important stuff and reinstall the operating system.